# How do you implement multisig functionality within a team in solana?

Tags: solana

I understand how to create multisig accounts as specified in the below documentation but am not sure how this works in practice. Suppose I have a partner, we both create a new keypair, and we both need to sign a transaction. The point is that I don't know his keypair and he doesnt know mine.

So how do you setup a process where we both sign a transaction from different computers neither knows the other's keypair info?

https://spl.solana.com/token

Answer (score 1):

For a multisig allowing for transaction signatures from unconnected computers, you'll want to check out the Serum multisig example program: https://github.com/project-serum/multisig

As you've noticed, the native multisig functionality in the SPL token program is limited in this domain.

Answer (score 1):

a bit late to this thread but wanted to share our latest solana multisig product here, in case you might find it useful. as Jon C mentioned, serum multisig and SPL token program are both great options and have been well adopted within the ecosystem. SPL token is more suited to DAO governance use case.

Snowflake Safe is gearing towards teams and secure individuals with a little more focus on the UX side.

DAPP : https://safe.snowflake.so
SDK : https://github.com/snowflake-so/snowflake-safe-sdk